# Cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0. Also, some modules are not found by cmake, though they are installed

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, arm, cmake-gui

I am trying to run opencv on Fedora 21 64-bit with ARM-compilers. I tried configuring it with Cmake 3.0.2 gui and i got this:

```
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.5.1
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.5.1
Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-g++
Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-g++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc
Check for working C compiler: /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detected version of GNU GCC: 45 (405)
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_W
Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_RETURN_TYPE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_ADDRESS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_SEQUENCE_POINT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY
Performing Test HAVE_C_WERROR_FORMAT_SECURITY - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
Looking for pthread.h
Looking for pthread.h - found
Check if the system is big endian
Searching 16 bit integer
Looking for sys/types.h
Looking for sys/types.h - found
Looking for stdint.h
Looking for stdint.h - found
Looking for stddef.h
Looking for stddef.h - found
Check size of unsigned short
Check size of unsigned short - done
Using unsigned short
Check if the system is big endian - little endian
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.8")
Looking for fseeko
Looking for fseeko - found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - found
Check size of off64_t
Check size of off64_t - failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Looking for assert.h
Looking for assert.h - found
Looking for fcntl.h
Looking for fcntl.h - found
Looking for io.h
Looking for io.h - not found
Looking for jbg_newlen
Looking for jbg_newlen - not found
Looking for mmap
Looking for mmap - found
Looking for search.h
Looking for search.h - found
Looking for string.h
Looking for string.h - found
Looking for unistd.h
Looking for unistd.h - found
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Failed
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
Could NOT find JPEG (missing:  JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Found JPEG: libjpeg  
Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FUNCTION_DECLARATION - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER
Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_PARAMETER - Failed
Found ZLIB: zlib (found version "1.2.7") 
Could NOT find PNG (missing:  PNG_LIBRARY) (found version "1.6.10")
Looking for semaphore.h
Looking for semaphore.h - found
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
  found gtk+-2.0, version 2.24.28
checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
  found gthread-2.0, version 2.42.2
checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
  package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
  package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
  package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
  package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
  package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
  package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
  package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
  package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
  package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
  package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
  package 'libdc1394-2' not found
checking for module 'libdc1394'
  package 'libdc1394' not found
checking for module 'libv4l1'
  package 'libv4l1' not found
checking for module 'libv4l2'
  package 'libv4l2' not found
Looking for linux/videodev.h
Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
Looking for linux/videodev2.h
Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
Looking for sys/videoio.h
Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
checking for module 'libavcodec'
  package 'libavcodec' not found
checking for module 'libavformat'
  package 'libavformat' not found
checking for module 'libavutil'
  package 'libavutil' not found
checking for module 'libswscale'
  package 'libswscale' not found
Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.8", minimum required is "2.0") 
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is at least version "2.7")
Cannot probe for Python/Numpy support (because we are cross-compiling OpenCV)
If you want to enable Python/Numpy support, set the following variables:
  PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH
  PYTHON_LIBRARIES
  PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success

General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.11 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Host:                        Linux 3.17.4-301.fc21.x86_64 x86_64
    Target:                      Linux
    CMake:                       3.0.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-g++  (ver 4.5.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    Precompiled headers:         YES

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python viz

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.28)
    GThread :                    YES (ver 2.42.2)
    GtkGlExt:                    NO
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg (ver 62)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

  Video I/O:
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      codec:                     NO
      format:                    NO
      util:                      NO
      swscale:                   NO
      gentoo-style:              NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    UniCap:                      NO
    UniCap ucil:                 NO
    V4L/V4L2:                    YES/YES
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Xine:                        NO

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use TBB:                     NO
    Use OpenMP:                  NO
    Use GCD                      NO
    Use Concurrency              NO
    Use C=:                      NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES

  OpenCL:
    Version:                     dynamic
    Include path:                /opt/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMD FFT:                 NO
    Use AMD BLAS:                NO

  Python:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.8)

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Documentation:
    Build Documentation:         NO
    Sphinx:                      NO
    PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  /usr/local

  cvconfig.h is in:              /opt/relarm
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
```

It shows many of the modules including gstreamer, dc1394 etc as not found. But i have installed them manually using sudo yum install commands.
Now that i run make command in Terminal it gave me the following error which shows that -lgtk-x11-2.0 cannot be found, though i have installed it with yum.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.5.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:
cannot find -lgtk-x11-2.0 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:520: recipe
for target 'lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11' failed make[2]: ***
[lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.11] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2025:
recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all'
failed make[1]: ***
[modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@osboxes relarm]#
```

Any help would be appreciated much.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either ask for more information if something wrong, either accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you met is because libraries you installed are for your native desktop architecture, and you're trying to link these with ARM compiler for ARM architecture, that won't work. You have to find ARM-architecture libraries to link with.

You have two ways out of the problem: α) Download the source code for the libraries you need by yourself, crosscompile these with your arm compiler, and finally use these libraries to link your application, either β) You may try [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/), it is a project that allows you to choose architecture, libraries you want to build, next it just downloads a source code and builds. After that step is finished, you may use its compilers and libraries to build your own application.

Comment: I am still trying to get a hang of buildroot, because i tried using that and it wasn't a success. I have downloaded the source code for the libraries, but there are so many files, which ones should i cross compile?

Comment: @UmarFarooq well, you decided to go a hard way. You would compile all source code in library, but it isn't hard. There's usually a script like `configure`, you ought to run it. It looks whether dependencies for compiling the library are satisfied, and prints an error if it wasn't, either creates a `Makefile` when everything okay. Then you just execute `make`, and… *Profit*. Sometimes there's no `configure` script, then there would be another one, the name you can find in README file which is always there.

Comment: The hard part there would be to setup compiler for cross-compilation, and compile all dependencies. You have to assign the compiler path to a variables, whose names I don't remember, but I think you can find it. By the way, I was thinking: did you look for the library in the end arm device? If it is there, I think you could just copy it to PC, and to try link with it. The name of the library is something like `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`

Comment: Let me get back to you after following your instructions.

Comment: @UmarFarooq well, I am here ☺

Comment: So I tried running that configure script in gtk source code and this is what i ended up with:
Makefile:1734: recipe for target 'gtk-query-immodules-2.0' failed
make[4]: *** [gtk-query-immodules-2.0] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/var/gtk+-2.24.0/gtk'
Makefile:2171: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/var/gtk+-2.24.0/gtk'
Makefile:1611: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/gtk+-2.24.0/gtk'
Makefile:623: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** .........

Comment: Also, i tried looking  for libgtk-x11-2.0 file in my arm device, but couldn't find it. 
I don't know what's wrong, every library works except for gtk and probably the dc1394 too which is messing up.

Comment: @UmarFarooq unfortunately I doesn't see in the output an actual error. Anyway, if the error wasn't shown in stdout, you can find it in the log. It is a file `configure.log`, if I correctly recall, either way, you will find in the current directory something with postfix `log`. So, in such cases you have to look at this log. Usually you will see there after a long list of variables, a long list of tests that was compiled. You have to find the failing test, and you will see the reason *(e.g. missing headers)*. Use the search for keywords *fail*, *error*, etc, because the file usually very big.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work anyway :/ Is there any other way to use a camera with my target arm without having to use gtk and few other libraries of highgui package?

Comment: @UmarFarooq sorry, I couldn't advice anything for camera usage, I haven't work with it. Tho I worked once with OpenCV, but it was in  usual PC, and I didn't used camera anyway, but rather screenshots *(I was cheating some flash game for fun ☺ )*

Comment: Well thanks for being generous enough to try atleast. I have moved onto Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed every library in it that wasn;t installing in F21. But now i am facing this error:
looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found, 
however when i look into the folder libavformat the avformat.h exists. you think you can help me with this? :/

Comment: @UmarFarooq it means that `libavformat` directory is not in paths in which compiler looks for headers. You can add the path with `-I` option, but I suspect it is something that you don't want to do, instead just [find which package hold this header](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=avformat.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) — here it is `libavformat-dev` —and just install it. Its headers would appear in paths of your compiler automagically.

Comment: @UmarFarooq `Well thanks for being generous enough to try atleast` by the way, it is untrue :Ь The things on which I tried to help in comments are beyond of your original question — of why you couldn't link with libraries from the repository to build an app for arm device.

Comment: It was already installed, infact i just had to copy that folder from usr/include to opencv/modules/highgui/src to make it work! Now i am one step ahead but this is where i am stuck now :p
so, cannot find lImath collect2: ld return.....
I've found the symbolic links but where should i put them now?

by the way, it is untrue :Ь - haha doesn't matter, you still helped anyway! :)

Comment: I guess i've found the solution to that, I just copied files from /usr/libs to my toolschain folder :)
let me deal with other errors now :)

Comment: @UmarFarooq hm… `/usr/include` should have been in compiler path by default… Anyway, instead of copying a files, it would be better if you just add that path to compiler with `-I` option